# ActiveMQ forwarding from local broker to a remote broker [with unstable connection]

Tags: jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, esb

I have the following problem: I have several sites with a local ActiveMQ broker that forwards to a remote broker (in a datacenter).  This connection is often unstable, and goes down several times a month for a few minutes or hours at a time.

Messages therefore need to wait on the local broker if the remote broker is not accessible at the moment.

I have the following ActiveMQ configuration:

```
    <networkConnectors>

            <networkConnector uri="static://(tcp://my-remote-broker:61616)" 
                name="myremotebroker" dynamicOnly="false"
                conduitSubscriptions="true"
                decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="false">

                    <!-- Exclude all destinations by default -->

                    <excludedDestinations>
                            <queue physicalName=">" />
                            <topic physicalName=">" />
                    </excludedDestinations>

                    <!-- Only forward these to our connection -->

                    <staticallyIncludedDestinations>
                            <topic physicalName="MySpecialTopic"/>
                    </staticallyIncludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
    </networkConnectors>
```

This forwards messages from the local broker (on topic MySpecialTopic), to the remote broker.  This works when the connection is stable.

However, I tried temporarily disabling the internet connection, so that the local broker lost connection with the remote broker.  At that point I sent a new message, which was enqueued on the local broker, but never arrived on the remote broker, **even after the local broker re-connected!**

Is there something in the ActiveMQ configuration that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What J2EE server and MQ are you running? Are you running WebSphere? Because if so, they have a really awesome feature called foreign buses that actually solves this very problem.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am testing this with ActiveMQ alone, since its control panel has a means to send messages manually for testing purposes.  Not running Websphere.  It basically needs to work on ActiveMQ by itself, so it's not dependent on an application server.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a TOPIC, which is hit or miss. This means that sending a message while the connection is down WILL be lost, which is standard behaviour for a topic ( only subscribers that are subscribed at the time of the send of the message will receive the message). (http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html)

You should use a Queue if you want the remote Consumer to receive the message OR should setup your subscribers as durable subscribers to assure they will receive messages at all times.. (http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html)

Comment: All my consumers are durable subscribers.   It's been a while since this problem occurred, and since I've moved to RabbitMQ.  The main problem I had was that occasionally ActiveMQ would disconnect/reconnect many times, and its KahaDB data directory would get corrupted.  In these cases, I couldn't even restart ActiveMQ without deleting the data/ directory.

Comment: Hmm.. i am familiar with the KahaDB problems , not with the durable consumers not getting the messages over a failover network.. however, there have been some strange other things in that area ( Several Advisory Queue's have the same issue and a bug that i have reported has been accepted for the next release) anyways.. glad you got it solved. BTW: how does rabbitMQ perform over the net ? We chose ActiveMQ at some point but i'm considering a move to RabbitMQ since stability remains an issue with ActiveMQ :s